# JQuery radio input on click form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, forms

I have a form that I want to submit when a radio button is selected. I already tried some methods to make it work, but it doesn't.

My form is something like this (just one radio option for ilustration, but the original one has 20 options):

```
<form action="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="votoscommentform" class="comment-form">
<div class="anuncio vitrine">
 <a href="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/ninasalvattori/">
   <div style="position: absolute; width: 172px; height: 285px;" class="fphover">&nbsp;</div>
   <img src="http://spartanas.com.br/novo/wp-content/plugins/nextcellent-gallery-nextgen-legacy/nggshow.php?pid=982" style="width:172px;height:285px">
 </a>
 <div class="infos">Nina Salvattori<br>Hotéis e Motéis</div>
 <div style="text-align:center"><strong>1 Voto</strong><br>
 <p><input onchange="this.form.submit();" value="6019" id="6019" name="comment" type="radio"><label for="6019">Votar</label></p></div></div>
<p class="form-submit">
<input name="submit" id="votarcomentform" value="Votar" type="submit">
<input name="comment_post_ID" value="6183" id="comment_post_ID" type="hidden">
<input name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0" type="hidden">
</p>
<input id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment" value="f33d177e03" type="hidden"><script>(function(){if(window===window.parent){document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name='_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';}})();</script>
</form>
```

As you can see this version I tried to submit it with onchange event, but I've tried with JQuery too:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[type="radio"][name="comment"]').click(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any javascript errors in the console? You can check that out using Developer Tools on Chrome or other browsers.

Comment: No errors. I've checked it first and it was with a jquery function error, but I fixed it...

Comment: Does it call the onclick event?  Put an alert before the submit and see if it's being called.

Comment: Yes, the alert is displayed with the following code '<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[type="radio"][name="comment"]').click(function() {
     alert ('It Works!');
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
}); 
</script>'

Answer (score 0):

you can use change event...

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[type="radio"][name="comment"]').change(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
}); 
</script>
```